# islower() works with "!= false" but not "== true"

Tags: c++, comparison-operators

So I wrote a basic program that checks for lowercase vowels in a string and displays how many it found.

I was using this at first:

```
for (char ch : str)
    {
        if (islower(ch) == true && isVowel(ch) == true) //isVowel is a function that
            strCount++;                                 //I made
    }
```

And my program wouldn't increment the counter but when I changed it to this:

```
for (char ch : str)
    {
        if (islower(ch) != false && isVowel(ch) == true)
            strCount++;
    }
```

It started working immediately. Why? Don't

```
if (islower(ch) != false)
```

and

```
if (islower(ch) == true)
```

do the exact same thing?

Comment: Try and get out of the habit of comparing explicitly with `true` - as you have seen, it can be dangerous. You should only ever use e.g. `if (condition)` rather than `if (condition == true)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`islower` returns an integral value different from zero (i.e., `true`) if indeed `ch` is a lowercase alphabetic letter. Zero (i.e., `false`) otherwise.

Comparing as `islower(ch) == true` it would be valid if `islower` returned `1`, which as mentioned above this isn't the case.

Consequently, rightfully `islower(ch) == true` doesn't work as you would expected.

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3041d3b4577d3d17)

Comment: That makes sense. What does islower() return if it is "true"?

Comment: It should probably be stressed that you just should never compare explicitly with `true` - it's redundant and potentially dangerous.

Comment: @user2240033 value returned isn't specified when `islower` succeeds. It is just an integral value different from 0. Thus, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @PaulR What you said applies for `islower` and generally for functions with the same behaviour. However, IMHO if a function returns a `bool` comparing with `true` is more readable and more straightforward to the eye, although by some might be considered redundant.

Comment: @40two: it's just good defensive programming - since any non-zero value evaluates to true in C or C++, and since a bool can be bigger than one bit, it's just safer to not test for true explicitly. For readability you can always test for `!= false` if you prefer.

Comment: Please note that std::islower with 2 parameters does in fact return a boolean, which can be slightly confusing if reading the man page too quickly. In any case as Paul noted, comparing booleans with true/false is a shocking bad habit.

Comment: @TomTanner: It is comparing `int` with `bool` which is a bad habit. Comparing `bool` with `true`/`false` is legitimate.

Comment: @Jarod42: even a function that supposedly returns `bool` can still return a value other than 0 or 1 in certain (admittedly buggy) cases, so it's still better to avoid comparison with `true`. Comparing with `false` is always fine of course.

Answer (score 5):

Quoted from cplusplus.com about return value of `islower()`:

> A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a lowercase alphabetic letter. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

So, just do `if (islower(ch))` instead of `if (islower(ch) == true)`